# How to detect anomalies?

Tags: neural-network, anomaly-detection, autoencoder

I have timeseries data with one value per day for a year. (there is one column with temperature data). I am using autoencoders to train a reconstruction model with mse loss.

Firstly, I normalized the data using the following code:

```
training_mean = preprocessed_data.mean()
training_std = preprocessed_data.std()
df_training_value = (preprocessed_data - training_mean) / training_std
```

After this I make a sequence with data. I am not sure if it's ok to choose 32 time stepts, but otherwise I can't fit the model.

```
TIME_STEPS = 32
def create_sequences(values, time_steps=TIME_STEPS):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(values) - time_steps + 1):
        output.append(values[i : (i + time_steps)])
    return np.stack(output)

x_train = create_sequences(df_training_value.values)
```

After this I make a sequential model with first layer:

```
layers.Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])),
        layers.Conv1D(
            filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding="same", strides=2, activation="relu"
        )
...
```

After that, I compute the mae loss on training and test data and I compare the test loss with a threshold, as I have seen on many tutorials.

```
anomalous_data_indices = []
for data_idx in range(0, len(df_test_value)): #(TIME_STEPS - 1, len(df_test_value) - TIME_STEPS + 1):
    if np.all(anomalies[data_idx - TIME_STEPS + 1 : data_idx]):
        anomalous_data_indices.append(data_idx)
```

The problem is that the test loss is always bigger than the training loss and I get that every value is anomaly. Should I calculate the loss on training and test samples using other method? Thankyou in advance!

Comment: How did you split train/test?

Comment: How are anomalous/normal samples distributed in your train and test sets?

Comment: Hi @JonNordby, thankyou for your time! Regarding the train/test data, I have one set of data for training and I made a copy for tests where I randomly changed some values, you can see the data in this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/110961/what-model-and-attributes-would-be-good-for-this-data). I made another validation set of data, close to test data, but I think I need a reconstruction model for my problem. The train test doesn't contain anomalous samples.

Comment: My data has same date, only different values. Could this be an issue ?